# Replacing Functionality of PIL (ImageDraw) in Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

So, Google App Engine doesn't look like it's going to include the Python Imaging Library [anytime soon](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=38&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary).   There is an [images api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/), but it's paltry, and inadequate for what I need.

I'm wondering what Python only (no C-extensions) there are that can replace the Image.paste and the ImageDraw modules.  I don't want to write them myself, but that is an option.  I'm also open to other solutions, such as "do the processing somewhere else, then call via api", if they're not *too* ugly.  (For the record, the solution I just suggested seems *pretty ugly* to me.)

How have others gotten around this?

(I'm not wedded to GAE, just exploring, and this looks like a deal breaker for my app.)

Notes:

For me, crop, resize is not enough. In particular I need

1. paste (replace part of an image with another.... can be faked with "compose")
2. draw (for drawing gridlines, etc.  Can be faked as well)
3. text (write text on an image, much harder to fake, unless someone wants to correct me)

Comment: Modern GAE has PIL, so this is mostly irrelevant these days.

Answer (score 2):

My skimpygimpy.sourceforge.net will do drawing and text, but it won't edit existing images (but it could be modified for that, of course, if you want to dive in).  It is pure python.  see it working on google apps, for example at
http://piopio.appspot.com/W1200_1400.stdMiddleware#Header51,

That's an experimental site that I'll be messing with.  The link may not work forever.

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising.  Maybe I can hack something together based on it.  I like the charts a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong. If you use the Python 2.7 runtime, you can use PIL (version 1.1.7) as documented here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27.
This article also explains how to enable PIL for your app.

BTW, the last comment in the bug you referenced also mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it has all features you want, but I have been messing with [PNGCanvas](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/Projects/PNGCanvas), and it does some things I have done before with PIL

Answer (score 1):

Now according to [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=38&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary) "On the Python 2.7 runtime, you can import PIL and use it directly. It's the real PIL, not a wrapper around the images API."