# Creating an image in Java (pixel by pixel) in memory and serving it dynamically in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, image-generation

I have an app that I am creating in Java in Google App Engine that needs to create an image from scratch (pixel by pixel, without too many higher level operations like rotating or text generation) on the server and then dynamically incorporate that image into the current html page. There is no need to store the image after it has been produced.

So far what I am thinking is using google's RPC service to send a Data URI string base64 encoded of the image

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,[data]">
```

back to the client which then can be used to switch the src of an image tag, and update the image on the client.

The step that I am having trouble with (surprise) is the actual image creation on the server, as GAE dos not white list java.awt image classes (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).

What I need help with is finding a library, or some different way of doing this, that will allow me to create an image dynamically on the server and send it to the client without refreshing the html page.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks,

Rowan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: create graphics without awt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169138/java-create-graphics-without-awt)

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly the same question with number of answers: [Java: create graphics without awt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169138/java-create-graphics-without-awt)